# Plotting slice 3D matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, slice

i'm working in a tomography project and i would like to plot 3d slice of a velocity model using `meshgrid` and `slice`. Something like [this](http://image.sciencenet.cn/album/201210/24/2010562fsnkfkkiscetcfk.jpg) or [this](http://people.rit.edu/pnveme/pigf/ThreeDGraphics/thrd_threev_slice_1.gif)

Here's my code

```
     c=100 %grid
        r= 5  %radius
        rt= 8 %height

         for i = 1:c
    for j = 1:c
        for k = 1:c
        jarak1 = sqrt(((i-1)-r)^2+((j-1)-r)^2);
        jarak2 = sqrt((i-r)^2+((j-1)-r)^2);
        jarak3 = sqrt(((i-1)-r)^2+(j-r)^2);
        jarak4 = sqrt((i-r)^2+(j-r)^2);
        jarak5 = k;
        if (jarak1 < r) &&(jarak2 < r) &&(jarak3 < r) &&(jarak4 < r) && (jarak5 < (rt+1))
            Vmodel(j,i,k)=1500;
           end
        end    
    end
end

    [X,Y,Z] =  meshgrid(0:c,0:c,0:c);
    xslice = 50; yslice = 50; zslice = 50;
    slice(X,Y,Z,Vmodel,xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

I expected a cylinder, got error message instead.

```
??? Error using ==> interp3 at 128
Matrices X,Y and Z must be the same size as V.

Error in ==> slice at 104
    vi = interp3(x,y,z,v,xi,yi,zi,method);
```

Any thought?

Comment: You need to pre-allocate for `Vmodel`, because otherwise with the `IF` conditional, it's not sizing upto the sizes of `X`, `Y` and `Z`. So, add, this before the loops - `Vmodel = zeros(c+1,c+1,c+1);`. Still not getting me a cylinder though, maybe the pre-allocation has to be something else?

Comment: Yes it worked. I modified the loops, i can get the cylinder now. Thanks!